# What special rules does the scala compiler have for the unit type within the type system

Tags: scala, functional-programming, static-typing

The `Unit` gets special handling by the compiler when generating byte code because it's analogous to `void` on the jvm. But conceptually as a type within the scala type system, it seems like it also gets special treatment in the language itself (examples below).

So my question is about clarifying this and understanding what mechanisms are used and if there really is special treatment for the `Unit` type.

---

**Example 1:**

For "normal" scala types like `Seq`, if a method returns `Seq`, then you must return `Seq` (or a more specific type that extends `Seq`)

```
def foo1: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
def foo2: Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
def foo3: Seq[Int] = "foo" // Fails
```

The first two examples compile because `List[Int]` and `Vector[Int]` are subtypes of `Seq[Int]`. The third one fails because `String` isn't.

But if I change the third example to return `Unit` though, it *will* compile and run without issue even though `String` *isn't* a subtype of `Unit`:

```
def foo3(): Unit = "foo" // Compiles (with a warning)
```

I don't know of any other type which this exception would be allowed for in scala. So does the compiler have special rules for the `Unit` type at the type system level, or is there some kind of more general mechanism at work e.g. an implicit conversion.

---

**Example 2:**

I'm also not clear how unit interacts in situations where variance rules would normally be applied.

For example, we sometimes hit this bug with `Future[Unit]` where we accidentally use `map` instead of `flatMap` and create a `Future[Future]`:

```
def save(customer: Customer): Future[Unit] = ... // Save to database

def foo: Future[Unit] = save(customer1).map(_ => save(customer2))
```

The `map` is creating a `Future[Future[Unit]]` and the compiler requires a `Future[Unit]`. Yet this compiles!

At first I thought this was because `Future[+T]` is covariant, but actually `Future[Unit]` isn't a subtype of `Unit` so it doesn't seem to be that.

If the type gets changed to `Boolean` for example, the compiler detects the bug:

```
def save(customer: Customer): Future[Boolean] = ...

def foo: Future[Boolean] = save(customer1).map(_ => save(customer2)) // Compiler fails this
```

And for every other non-`Unit` type it won't compile (except `Any` because `Future[Any]` happens to be a subtype of `Any` by coincidence).

So does the compiler have special rules in this case? Or is there a more general process happening?

Comment: basically, if you declare some type as Unit (a value or a function return for example), the compiler converts whatever value it has to Unit. not sure if it's the answer you are looking for, or if you are looking for more internal details..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to answer the title question for more coverage. `Unit` gets special treatment in a few places, more than what's going on in those code examples. In part, this is because `Unit` is a figment of the compiler that reduces to `void` on the JVM.

---

**Value Discarding**

This is the most surprising case for people. Any time the expected type of some value is `Unit`, the compiler tacks on `Unit` at the end of the expression that produces the value, according to the [SLS - 6.26.1](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-conversions):

> If `ee` has some value type and the expected type is `Unit`, `ee` is converted to the expected type by embedding it in the term `{ ee; () }`.

Thus,

```
def foo3(): Unit = "foo"
```

becomes:

```
def foo3(): Unit = { "foo" ; () }
```

Likewise,

```
def foo: Future[Unit] = save(customer1).map(_ => save(customer2))
```

becomes:

```
def foo: Future[Unit] = save(customer1).map(_ => { save(customer2); () })
```

The *benefit* of this is that you don't need to have the last statement of a method have the type `Unit` if you don't want to. This benefit is small however, because if the last statement of your method that returns `Unit` isn't a `Unit`, that *usually* indicates an error, which is why there is a warning flag for it (`-Ywarn-value-discard`).

In general, I find it better to return a more specific type, if possible, rather than returning `Unit`. For example, when saving to a database, you may be able to return the saved value (perhaps with a new ID, or something).

---

**Value Class**

`Unit` is a value class created by the Scala compiler, with only one instance (if it needs to be instantiated as a class at all). This means that it compiles down to the primitive `void` on the JVM, unless you treat it as a class (e.g. `().toString`). It has its very own section in the specification, [SLS - 12.2.13](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/12-the-scala-standard-library.html#class-unit).

---

**Empty Block Type**

From the [SLS - 6.11](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#blocks), the default type of an empty block is assumed to be `Unit`. For example:

```
scala> val x = { }
x: Unit = ()
```

---

**Equals**

When comparing a `Unit` to another `Unit` (which must be the same object, since there is only one), the compiler will emit a special warning to inform you something is likely wrong in your program.

```
scala> ().==(())
<console>:12: warning: comparing values of types Unit and Unit using `==' will always yield true
       ().==(())
            ^
res2: Boolean = true
```

---

**Casting**

You can cast anything to a `Unit`, as the compiler will optimize it away (though it's unclear to me if value discarding takes over after type inference).

```
object Test {
  val a = "a".asInstanceOf[Unit]
  val b = a
}
```

becomes:

```
object Test extends Object {
  def <init>(): Test.type = {
    Test.super.<init>();
    ()
  };
  private[this] val a: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit = scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT;
  <stable> <accessor> def a(): Unit = ();
  private[this] val b: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit = scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT;
  <stable> <accessor> def b(): Unit = ()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I think you mean 6.26.1, not 6.22.1 when you link the language specification though.

Answer (score 15):

As written in the [scala language specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-conversions) chapter 6.26.1:

> **Value Discarding**
>
> If e has some value type and the expected type is Unit, e is converted
>   to the expected type by embedding it in the term { e; () }.

Answer (score 14):

rethab's answer already gave you the link to the spec; just let me add that

- you can *disable* this (make the warning an error) through the `-Xfatal-warnings` compiler flag
- you'll get better *messages* with the `-Ywarn-value-discard` flag; for `foo3` the compiler warning will be the more informative `discarded non-Unit value`

Note that this "any to Unit" conversion is compiler magic, so neither `-Yno-predef` or `-Yno-imports` will disable it; you do need the flags above. I consider this being part of the language specification an error, as if for some reason you want this dubious behavior you can just add something like

```
implicit def any2Unit(a: Any): Unit = ()
```

while opting-out of it requires an unsupported (by definition, as it *breaks* the specification) compiler flag.

I also recommend [wartremover](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover), where you have [this](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover/#nonunitstatements) and much more.